# Objective-C assigning variables question for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The following piece of code can be written in two ways. I would like to know what are the pros and cons of each. If possible I would like to stick with the one liner.

1)

```
UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];

self.view.backgroundColor = background;

[background release];
```

2)

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];
```

Any issues with releasing memory etc. with #2? I'm new to Objective-C and would like to follow the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one more way that this can be written, and is commonly used for objects that do not need to be retained in memory:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];
```

This way, no memory management is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Both are fine. It's just personal preference. I usually do it way #2, making sure to add it to the autorelease pool so we don't create memory leaks:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use #2, you'll need to send the object an "autorelease" message, to add it to the autorelease pool, otherwise, you've got a memory leak.

So

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]] autorelease];
```

Remember the contract, you alloc/init, you release OR add to the autorelease pool.

Edit: Correct, the other two answers are mentioning what apple calls "convenience methods" that create an object that's already been added to the autorelease pool for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. All answers helped and make sense.